# Best way to handle Cross Domain on SharePoint Intranet w/o server side, silverlight, DBC etc

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, cross-domain, intranet

I'm working on a Microsoft internal SharePoint site, and I need to pull in List data from a cross domain SharePoint site.

I don't want to use Silverlight, for various reasons, and Business Data Connectivity is not possible right now.

Is there a simple way to use JavaScript or something like it to accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"*Simple*?" Not exactly. Given your requirements, particularly "*w/o server side*," this isn't possible.

However, if you can forego that requirement, you have a few options for enabling cross-domain requests.

#### CORS

There's [decent support](http://caniuse.com/#cors) for [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) for `XMLHttpRequest` and Microsoft's [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(VS.85).aspx). Though, this will require that the remote server include the proper headers in the response to allow your origin/domain to make the request.

```
<% Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") %>
```

#### JSONP

A common option is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which loads the resource in a `<script>` with a `callback` parameter with the name of a global function. Since JSON is based on JavaScript literals, this won't have the same browser-support issues, but the remote server will have to know how to construct the output and it's limited to `GET` requests.

```
// <script src="http://other.dom/resource?callback=loadResource"></script>

loadResource( [ {"id": 1, "name": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "bar"} ] );
```

#### Server-side Proxy

If the remote server you're requesting from can't (or won't) be adjusted to support cross-domain requests, you're pretty much left with making a Server-Side Proxy on your server.

The general pattern is described at [AjaxPatters.org](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy) and a number of .NET implementations can be found, including [John Chapman's](http://www.sharepointjohn.com/aspnet-proxy-page-cross-domain-requests-from-ajax-and-javascript/) and the [Cross-Domain Proxy](http://crossdomainproxy.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: I'll give JSONP a try and let you know. Server side simply isn't allowed by the IT team that governs the sites. Silverlight can do this, but it's much slower and is really a sub-optimal experience for the end user.

Comment: This is one of the best, concise descriptions I have seen in one place.  Thank you!

Comment: should i add the header in default page of the site?

Answer (score -2):

You can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to get data from a SharePoint list. [See this article.](http://sharepointresource.com/2011/03/11/jquery-getting-data-from-a-sharepoint-list/)

Comment: omg, I should read the posts more carefully before answering. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Wesley how can i access for cross domain?